# graphicsmagic not installed in google cloud functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

i m working in a project in firebase that uses graphics magic to convert images to pdf
it's working fine in local emulator
but doesnt in production

> Error: Could not execute GraphicsMagick/ImageMagick: gm "convert" "./0" "./a4.pdf" this most likely means the gm/convert binaries can't be found at ChildProcess. (/workspace/node_modules/gm/lib/command.js:232:12) at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13) at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20) at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12) at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)

knowing that in the cloud functions documentation they said that graphics magic is included in the environement
see : https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/imagemagick

Edit : gm requires installation (apt get install), i can't do that in cloud functions , cuz i dont have access to the machine.
i'm working now with pdfkit, its does the same job and doesnt require installation (requires npm install tho)

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's [easy to read, copy, and search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/807126).  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to include `gm` on your dependencies. You can do so by running:

```
npm install gm
```

And have your dependencies look like:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@google-cloud/storage": "^5.0.0",
  "@google-cloud/vision": "^2.0.0",
  "gm": "^1.23.1"
}
```

I just followed this [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/functions/imagemagick) and it's working fine on Nodejs10 runtime.

**UPDATE**: It looks like there's an [open issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/806) on GitHub  about this problem. I suggest you put a comment in there and provide detailed information similar to what the reporter did.

Comment: i've already done that, as i said , it's working in my local machine

Comment: do i need to do something on the cloud ?

Comment: My bad. You can't directly install the library on GCF runtime.  I've updated my answer now. Please take a look.