# Firebase/Google Cloud Functions "Could not execute GraphicsMagick/ImageMagick"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I'm running into an issue with running a GraphicsMagick script inside of a Node 14 cloud function deployed through Google's Firebase platform.

**What i'm trying to do**
On our platform, when a user uploads a PDF file, we need to store PNG copies of each page to display on the front-end (when a PNG item hit's the bucket, thumbnails are also generated to save on bandwidth & loading times). The user uploads a PDF file, when it hits the bucket a cloud function fires which uses the `pdf-page-counter` library to count how many pages there are before entering a map to loop through. Inside of the loop, we have access to `i` which is the current page in the PDF. I then employ the use of the `pdf2pic` library to convert the PDF page into a PNG image, but this is where the problem occurs.

**pdf2pic code in the cloud function**
Below is the code in the cloud function which I don't believe is the issue, more the fact that the GraphicsMagick/Imagemagick modules are not being found inside the cloud function environment:

```
// Establish some options to pass into the pdf2pic conversion
const baseOptions = {
   width: 2550,
   height: 3300,
   density: 330,
   savePath: tempNewPath,
};
// Call the fromPath method with the file location and base options 
const convert = fromPath(tempFilePath, baseOptions);
// Convert the pdf page to an image
await convert(pageNumber);
```

**The error I get when running the above code**

```
Error: Could not execute GraphicsMagick/ImageMagick: gm "convert" "-density" "330x330" "-quality" "75" "-[0]" "-resize" "2550x3300!" "-compress" "jpeg" "/tmp/YgGxvF9IxXAdJTOH4HTT.png/untitled.1.png" this most likely means the gm/convert binaries can't be found
```

**What i've already tried**

- There was another question for this exact topic [opened here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65602524/graphicsmagic-not-installed-in-google-cloud-functions) but it hasn't given me much success when I tried the fixes described in there.
- I included the `gm` library through `npm install gm` in my functions directory and deployed to firebase but still no success.
- Upgraded the function runtime from Node 10 to Node 14
- Setup ghostscript as per the pdf2pic libraries requirements

So as you can tell i'm kind of at a dead end. The issue to me seems like the cloud function can't find the GraphicsMagick modules as per the error, but everything I've done so far to attempt to "install" it have not seemed to work so any advice on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

ImageMagick is no longer available on the Google Cloud Platform since they upgrade their platform. They upgrade Ubuntu from release 18.04 to Ubuntu 22.04.
As you can read in the list of the packages that are included in this version:
[System Packages Included in Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/system-packages)
ImageMagick is no longer available!

I am also very disappointed about that and looking for a solution.

You can vote on Google IssueTracker to make this issue more important to solve for their team. I have also voted for that!
You can vote here: [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/254843962)

Answer (score 0):

I can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/system-packages) that ImageMagick comes already installed with the Cloud Functions environment but GraphicsMagick doesn't.

If you have tried all the above without success, you can always upload your own GraphicsMagick compiled binary along with your Cloud Function and use something like [`child_process.exec`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) to execute it in your code. Your binary will have to be compiled for your target platform, and I believe [this](https://download.imagemagick.org/ImageMagick/download/binaries/magick) is what you are looking for.

Then, your code in `index.js` should look like:

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");

exec("[YOUR_IMAGEMAGICK_COMMAND]", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  //You can check outputs.
  console.log(stderr);
});
```